# XML Drawable place image 1/4 from top

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to create a "splash screen" preview theme as per:

- [Android App Launching Made Gorgeous](http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/)
- [Fast splash screens on Android](http://www.cutehacks.com/blog/2014/01/13/splash-screens)

i.e. a theme that places an XML drawable as the background, which then gets displayed while Android loads up the first activity layout.

I have been using these techniques on basic layouts for years, all the time *assuming* that there was no solution for more complex layouts, like this question. Today I decided to question the assumption.

---

It is easy to overlay one image on top of another, and to centre the smaller image using a `LayerDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/logo" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

---

What I want to do is **place the logo exactly 1/4 of the screen height down from the top**.

Is there a solution to this yet, that can be used in an XML drawable file?

---

Update based on [comment by DavidH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32356632/xml-drawable-place-image-1-4-from-top?noredirect=1#comment52587370_32356632) - Can a custom `LayerDrawable` subclass be added to a drawable XML file, which is then used as part of an application theme?

Comment: You're better off using a layout for that.

Comment: Great reads indeed. Sorry for not having anything better to offer, but I think you'll have to write a custom LayerDrawable class and override the onDraw() where you do: canvas.save() > canvas.translate() > logoDrawable.draw(canvas) > canvas.restore().

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, that's not possible. You might want to consider using `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new CustomSplashLayerDrawable());` early in your Activity's `onCreate()`

Comment: @DavidH If you get round to trying that, you'll find the effect is not quite the same. The application theme is displayed almost immediately. Anything done from inside an `Activity` takes a long time, as the activity itself needs to be created, layout inflated etc. That's what makes Cyril's app launching so gorgeous, it happens right away.

Comment: Oh okay...too bad I haven't been able to be of much help. Good luck!

Comment: @David with a question like this, thinking out of the box is always appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible. Relative measurements inside XML layouts are not supported.